# Setting ansible environment in Role task

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to set the environment for a command to run, and no matter what I do, I can't seem to get the environment to be set properly for a `command` task.

I'm running this task in a role called `test-kitchen`

```
- name: Debug
  command: echo $PATH > /tmp/pathdoc && echo $GEM_PATH > /tmp/gempath
  environment:
    PATH: "{{ lookup('env', 'PATH') }}:/usr/local/bin:"
    GEM_PATH: "{{ rvm1_install_path }}/gems/ruby-{{ ruby_version }}:\
               {{ rvm1_install_path }}/gems/ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@global"
```

I'm calling the role from a playbook that looks like this.

```
- hosts: all 
  become: true
  roles:
  - kitchen-tester
```

I've tried setting the variables in the role vars, in the playbook vars, and now in the task, but no matter what I do, the file `/tmp/pathdoc` shows this path `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` and the GEM_PATH variable isn't even set.

Am I missing something dumb? 
Ansible v2.6

Answer (score 0):

Few observations:

The output for the above scenario is this:

```
changed: [192.168.3.103] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["echo", "$PATH", ">", "/tmp/pathdoc", "&&", "echo", "$GEM_PATH", ">", "/tmp/gempath"], "delta": "0:00:00.002654", "end": "2018-07-11 11:24:02.994448", "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "echo $PATH > /tmp/pathdoc && echo $GEM_PATH > /tmp/gempath", "_uses_shell": false, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "warn": true}, "module_name": "command"}, "rc": 0, "start": "2018-07-11 11:24:02.991794", "stderr": "", **"stdout": "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/bin: > /tmp/pathdoc && echo /tmp/gems/ruby-1:/tmp/gems/ruby-1@global > /tmp/gempath", "stdout_lines"**: **["/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/bin: > /tmp/pathdoc && echo /tmp/gems/ruby-1:/tmp/gems/ruby-1@global > /tmp/gempath"]**, "warnings": []}
```

looking at the stdout portion of the above output, you will notice that GEM_PATH and PATH are set but they are not individual echo commands as you are thinking they are just one single echo command and rest of string is argument to this command.
Another thing is grouping of commands with && is something iam not aware of. I use ';' so if you are sure && can be used for grouping use it.

So for intended result use shell or call shell in command.

Hope that helps.

Regards
Sudhakar

Comment: `&&` (logical `AND`) is usually (but not necessarily) a better choice than `;` because in a sequence of multiple commands it will stop as soon as it encounters an error.

Answer (score -1):

documentation says for `command` module:

> The given command will be executed on all selected nodes. It will not be processed through the shell, so variables like $HOME and operations like “<”, “>”, “|”, “;” and “&” will not work (use the shell module if you need these features).

try using the `shell` module instead:

> The shell module takes the command name followed by a list of space-delimited arguments. It is almost exactly like the command module but runs the command through a shell (/bin/sh) on the remote node.

Also, keep in mind the `lookup` plugin executes on the Ansible host, not the remote.